# How to append query to previously selected query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

```
public function gettopfilteredcourse($filtertype, $topfiltername, $filterid){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM course c
          INNER JOIN category s
          ON c.categoryId=s.categoryId
          INNER JOIN users u
          ON c.userId=u.userId";

  if($topfiltername == 'trash'){
     $sql .= " WHERE isCompleted='3'";
  } else if($topfiltername == 'forapproval'){
     $sql .= " WHERE isCompleted='1'";
  } else if($topfiltername == 'drafts'){
     $sql .= " WHERE isDraft='1'";
  } else {
     $sql .= " WHERE isCompleted='2'";
  }

  if($filtertype == 'free'){
     $sql .= " AND c.fee=''";
  } else if($filtertype == 'paid'){
     $sql .= " AND c.fee!=''";
  } else {
     $sql .= " AND c.categoryId='$filterid' ";
  } 
   $query=$this->db->query($sql);
   return $query;
}
```

In the first if condition `$topfiltername == 'forapproval'` is selected, it executed properly. When comes to second if condition `$filtertype == 'paid'`, I want to be append this to be with `$topfiltername == 'forapproval'`, but it always appended with first if condition else statement `$sql .= " WHERE isCompleted='2'";`. How to do please help me.

[image: filter]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using codeigniter.use the database library.
codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html